# Preventing UI interaction to the parent view

Tags: macos

I have a WKWebView (loaded with Google) in my macOS app. On top of that, I have added a subview (Gray one, with a white box) as follows.

```
let controller = MyViewController()
self.addChildViewController(controller)
self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
```

Eventhough my new view is at the top, still I am able to click the links in the webview.

[image]

I have been overriding the `mouseDown` in my view and block the click. But, if I move the mouse over the links, it is changing to pointed hand mouse.

Is there any way to block the user interaction at my new view itself, so that it does not pass through to the webview?

Thanks in advance.